# GDB throws error while stepping into at breakpoint

Tags: c, gdb, buffer-overflow

I am trying to follow a video tutoial on buffer overflow from this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&list=PLSBETBOXVwoGBGpCXJY5q0VtyCEOiVq7V&v=RF7DF4kfs1E)
and below is the code which I am trying.

```
#include <stdio.h>

GetInput() 
{
    char buffer[8];

    gets(buffer);
    puts(buffer);   
}

main()
{
   GetInput();       
   return 0;
}
```

I am getting an isssue in gdb debugging, while I step onto i.e at line 7, I get the below error:

```
_IO_gets (buf=0xbffff458 "k\204\004\b") at iogets.c:33
33  iogets.c: No such file or directory.
```

I am following exactly the same steps as mentioned in the tutorial.
I am using 32 bit Kali linux on virtual box

Can anyone help me to get through this problem.

Comment: Do not use `gets()` it's a deprecated old dangerous function. If the tutorial suggests gets it's either bad or too old, find another tutorial. Also, your `main()` is wrong too. Have you compiled with *gcc* warning flags like `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`?

Comment: Yes I know but for the sake of learning I am trying it. The program gets compiled very well and works fine. I am getting problem only while debugging it.

Comment: Don't learn something that encourages bad programming practices and you will never use because was deprecated by recent c standards. Try another tutorial, trust me. And it compiles without warnings but enable them and you should see some warnings like *`gets()` is deprecated* and *`main()` has no return type*. `GetInput()` has no return type either, so your compiler must complain if you enable warnings.

Comment: In my case *gcc-5.1* the compiler warns about the implicit declaration of `gets()` probably because, it's using the c11 standard by default where that functions ceased to exist. It also warns about the other things you mention. Compiled it with `-std=c89` and it still tells me that `gets()` is **DEPRECATED**.

Comment: the program runs fine, buts its gdb which throws this error while debugging it.

Comment: Don't you think it's related to what I am telling you? Also, does the tutorial define `GetInput()` like that? If it does, please drop the tutorial and find a good one. And I didn't say that the program should not compile or run.

Comment: I just answered your question, but please follow my advice. You know, not only tutorials can teach you. And this particular one, will not help you at all. Ask any experienced [tag:c] programmer.

Comment: Yes I will act on your advice, meanwhile I was searching for some other tutorials. Thanks for your answer and suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The author of the post is following a buffer overflow exploitation course. Instead of helping him, everyone jumped with off topic information. We all know that the code is wrong, but then, how you are supposed to learn buffer overflow exploitation if not on a bad code ?

In this case debugging didn't work properly because location of the debug file is somewhere else.

```
(gdb) show debug-file-directory
The directory where separate debug symbols are searched for is "/usr/lib/debug"
```

Execute the following in gdb

```
(gdb) set debug-file-directory
```

Now you will be able to debug your code. HF

Comment: Thank you very much. I was also following a BO video course and came across this issue. googling landed here and this actually helped me solve the issue. thanks!

Comment: Came across this error while reversing a compiled binary.
It did resolve my error which happens to be exactly the one describe by OP.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simply that, *glibc* source code is missing. It doesn't matter anyway because the bug is not likely in *glibc*, in this case your code is using the dangerous, deprecated `gets()` and hence it can easily overflow the `buffer` array, causing *Undefined Behavior*.